# Python List of Lists How to delete list elements in adjListCopy by index?

Tags: python, list

```
adjList = [[1,2,3,7], [2,1,3,7], [3,1,2,4], [4,3,5,6], [5,4,6], [6,4,5], [7,1,2]]
adjListCopy= adjList[:]
v=int(raw_input("Enter the node v to be deleted along with its neighbourhood"))
copy = adjList[v-1]
print(copy)
del adjList[v-1]
print adjList
print adjListCopy
```

Output:

```
Enter the node v to be deleted along with its neighbourhood2
[2, 1, 3, 7]
[[1, 2, 3, 7], [3, 1, 2, 4], [4, 3, 5, 6], [5, 4, 6], [6, 4, 5], [7, 1, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3, 7], [2, 1, 3, 7], [3, 1, 2, 4], [4, 3, 5, 6], [5, 4, 6], [6, 4, 5], [7, 1, 2]]
```

```
print adjListCopy
for i in range(len(copy)):
    print(copy[i])
    for j in range(len(adjListCopy)):
        if copy[i]==adjListCopy[j][0]:
            print adjListCopy[j] ***************
print adjListCopyFor1
```

At the place where I made ********* I would like to write del instead of print to solve my purpose but it throws an error.

Comment: Have you considered using `while` instead? with it, you can delete without jumping elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm currently  at my phone. But i can  tell  you  that  you can't delete indexes  while  you iterate or loop over a list. You can take a copy (`copy.deepcopy`) of the list, iterate over the copy and  delete by the index from the original.

Comment: That won't change anything, the indexes are still the same so he will be out of range eventually

Comment: How? He want a delete for only one element. Or not?

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove an element of the list that you are iterating over. I think you should `del adjList[i]` and not `adjListCopy[j]`. Otherwise you can iterate over adjList ( `for j in range(len(adjList)):`) and delete from adjListCopy.

Comment: but that way you would change the order of values and after the first element gets removed you would start deleting wrong values or even get a index-out-of-range-error

Comment: it works in the specific instance, so to remove only one element. Otherwise you need to store the indexes of the matching elements and remove those items later.

Answer (score 0):

You cant just itterate over range(len(adjListCopy)) because the size changes as you delete element you should do:

```
j = 0
while j < len(adjListCopy):
    if copy[i]==adjListCopy[j][0]:
        del adjListCopy[j]
    else:
       j++
```

Answer (score 0):

````
adjListCopy= adjList[:]
v=int(raw_input("Enter the node v to be deleted along with its neighbourhood"))
copy = adjList[v-1]
print(copy)
del adjList[v-1]
print adjList
print adjListCopy
print adjListCopy
for i in range(len(copy)):
    print(copy[i])
    for idx,j in enumerate(adjListCopy):
        if copy[i]==adjListCopy[idx][0]:
            del adjListCopy[idx]
            break
print adjListCopy
l1 = []
for i in range(len(adjListCopy)):
    l1.append(adjListCopy[i][0])
print l1

a=1
print(l1)

result = []
for i in range(len(adjListCopy)):
    l2 = []
    l2.append(adjListCopy[i][0])
    for j in range(1,len(adjListCopy)):
        x = adjListCopy[i][j]
        if x not in l1:
            print("Found: ", x)
            print(j)
            l2.append(x)
        j+=1
    result.append(l2)
    print('****')
print result ```
````